# Is it possible to use MINOS as a stand alone package (without having to use AMPL or other modeling system)? If yes, then where can I get the package?

Tags: fortran

**MINOS** is a Fortran software package for solving linear and nonlinear mathematical optimization problems. MINOS (Modular In-core Nonlinear Optimization System) may be used for linear programming, quadratic programming, and more general objective functions and constraints, and for finding a feasible point for a set of linear or nonlinear e qualities and inequalities.